# como descarregar texto em div

Tags: javascript

por favor, retirem o endereco do site...

Duas perguntas:

1. Como posicionar a div aId2 sob a div aId1;
2. Como descarrar texto na div de acordo com a mudança da imagem;

Exemplo:

```
texto1 aparecer com imagem1
texto2 aparecer com imagem2
texto3 aparecer com imagem3
```

Código:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-size: 98%;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function slide1(){
document.getElementById('id').src="http://site/imagem/foto-0.jpg";
setTimeout("slide2()", 3000);
document.getElementById('aId').href="link1.html";
document.getElementById('aId').alt="slid1";
}

function slide2(){
document.getElementById('id').src="http://site/imagem/foto-1.jpg";
setTimeout("slide3()", 3000);
document.getElementById('aId').href="link2.html";
document.getElementById('aId').alt="slid2";
}

function slide3(){
document.getElementById('id').src="http://site/imagem/foto-2.jpg";
setTimeout("slide1()", 3000);
document.getElementById('aId').href="link3.html";
document.getElementById('aId').alt="slid3";
}
</script>
<body onLoad="slide1()">
<div id="aId1" style="position: relative;">
<a id="aId"><img id="id" width="100%"></a>
</div>
<div id="aId2" style="position: relative; transparent; width:80%;height:50%;margin-top:0;margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; text-align: center">
<h1>texto slid 1</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inserindo a `div` na primeira e alterando os estilos, como o `position` para `absolute`.

Para alterar o texto use: `document.querySelector('#aId2 h1').textContent`

**Veja:**

```js
function slide1(){
document.getElementById('id').src="http://site/imagem/foto-0.jpg";
setTimeout("slide2()", 3000);
document.getElementById('aId').href="link1.html";
document.querySelector('#aId2 h1').textContent="slid1";
}

function slide2(){
document.getElementById('id').src="http://site/imagem/foto-1.jpg";
setTimeout("slide3()", 3000);
document.getElementById('aId').href="link2.html";
document.querySelector('#aId2 h1').textContent="slid2";
}

function slide3(){
document.getElementById('id').src="http://site/imagem/foto-2.jpg";
setTimeout("slide1()", 3000);
document.getElementById('aId').href="link3.html";
document.querySelector('#aId2 h1').textContent="slid3";
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="slide1()">
<div id="aId1" style="position: relative;">
   <a id="aId"><img id="id" width="100%"></a>
   <div id="aId2" style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
      <h1>texto slid 1</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

> Você pode alterar os estilos e posicionar a `div` onde quiser.

Comment: vlw professor!! obrigado.
fico feliz pelo seu conhecimento brilhante em português e ter entendido o que gostaria de fazer.

Comment: rs.. obg, mas não diria "brilhante", diria "básico" :D

Comment: não não. foi brilhante sim. e acredite, tem muito básico para tu aprender ainda. para nossa sorte, todos que postamos, você é um cara muito inteligente. deveria lecionar...;) sucesso!

Comment: Evandro, não deixe perguntas em aberto. Marque ✓ em uma resposta que resolveu seu problema. Caso as respostas não resolveram, questione, mas é importante finalizar as perguntas, esse é o foco da comunidade. Abs!

Comment: não localizei a opção para realizar esta operação.

Comment: Ao lado esquerdo da resposta, abaixo das setas de votação tem um ícone ✔️